# Selenium: Unable to Scrape Text Via XPath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the text:

> 10 hours and 51 minutes

from the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="a-box-inner">
<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini prime-ad-banner-content" data-testid="">
<div class="a-row shipment" data-testid="order-box-0" data-orderid="0">
<div class="a-row">
<div class="a-row shipping-group">
<div class="a-row" data-testid="">
<div class="a-row a-color-success a-size-medium">
<span class="a-text-bold" data-promisetype="delivery">Guaranteed delivery date:</span>
<span class="a-color-success a-text-bold">
<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary fasttrack-span hidden a-text-normal" style="display: inline;">
<span class="fasttrackexpired hidden" style="display: none;">
<span class="fasttrackavailable fasttrackcountdown hidden a-text-normal" style="display: inline;">
If you order in the next
<span data-field="fasttrackcountdown">10 hours and 51 minutes</span>
(
<a class="a-size-mini" href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=chk_ship_ft_details_pri?ie=UTF8&nodeId=3510241" target="AmazonHelp">Details</a>
)
</span>
<div id="a-popover-" class="a-popover-preload">
<div id="a-popover-" class="a-popover-preload">
<input type="hidden" value="39399" name="fasttrackExpiration">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="countdownThreshold">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="showSimplifiedCountdown">
<input type="hidden" value="countdownId-0" name="countdownId">
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="a-row a-spacing-small">
<div class="a-row">
```

I'm using the XPath:

```
.//*[@id='spc-orders']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[3]/span[2]/span
```

However although I'm able to identify this element using Firebug as well as with Eclipse - when I try using `getText` on this element I get nothing in return. In other words, I'm unable to scraped previous mentioned values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This XPath

```
//span[@data-field='fasttrackcountdown']
```

will select this element

```
<span data-field="fasttrackcountdown">10 hours and 51 minutes</span>
```

in your HTML, as requested.

Comment: Hi Thanks but I just tested it and it does not work. To test it yourself add any product to cart on Amazon, navigate to checkout and right before you place order you will see this screen with countdown. Ex. product: https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Apple-Certified-Lightning-Cable/dp/B010S9N6OO  Note: You need Amazon Prime to see this screen. Once again, in Firebug I can identify the element with either one of the XPath's provided but Selenium is unable to get the actual values for some reason. Note: The values seen keep changing every minute but I don't know how/if this influences anything.

Comment: The XPath is correct (but perhaps your data is not loaded at the time you're applying it, or perhaps there are other occurrences in the full data).   Sorry, but I'm not testing against Amazon's servers, which is almost certainly a violation of their terms of service.  You ought to being going through proper channels and using their API.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying your xPath is correct then It might be timing, at the time when you're going to find element, may be it wouldn't present with text, you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible with  `cssSelector` as `span[data-field='fasttrackcountdown']` as below(Assuming you are using Java) :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span[data-field='fasttrackcountdown']")));
el.getText();
```

If still you are not able to find text, you should use `getAttribute("innerHTML")` as below :-

```
el.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Or try using `getAttribute("textContent")` as below :-

```
el.getAttribute("textContent");
```

Hope it helps...:)